# how can i properly copy this file to another directory in Ubuntu 14.0

Tags: django, file, ubuntu, directory, copy

```
    cp -i /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/admin/base_site.html  /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/admin
```

I am trying to 'CUSTOMIZE MY PROJECT TEMPLATE' from the Django 1.8 POLLS tutorial
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/intro/tutorial02/

but no avail, i am having a hard time trying to copy the "base_site.html" file to the "django/contrib/admin/templates"

help me learn!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may misunderstand the tutorial, It said: copy it from the default directory into your custom directory, and make changes, it seems that you command above is trying to duplicate the file.

first, find your Django source file location:

```
python -c "
import sys
sys.path = sys.path[1:]
import django
print(django.__path__)"
```

you will get a link, go deep into the folder, find that template, then copy the `base_site.html` to your project's template folder.

Comment: There was a misunderstanding. lol thank you for clarifying, it works!